# Подсчёт количества значений Excel

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите пожалуйста формулу для подсчёта значений из колонки "А", если значения повторяются.

Имеется колонка "А", в ней находятся номера участков. Номера участков повторяются.
Так же есть колонка "I" с номерами секторов от 2 до 6.

Необходимо подсчитать количество участков в каждом секторе и вывести в отдельные ячейки! Главное условие, что бы одинаковые номера участков считались за 1

P.S Использую Google Sheets
[image: табличка с данными]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`L2` и вниз:

```
=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($L$1:L1;$I$2:$I$15)=0;$I$2:$I$15))
```

`M2` и вниз:

```
=СЧЁТ(1/ЧАСТОТА(($I$2:$I$15=L2)*($A$2:$A$15);($I$2:$I$15=L2)*($A$2:$A$15)))-1
```

Обе - формулы массива, вводятся сочетанием клавиш `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (должны обрамиться фигурными скобками).

Корректно работают при наличии пустых ячеек в диапазонах.

Comment: Сектора пронумеровались от 6 до 2, а вот в ячейках подсчёта постоянно значения "-1"

=ArrayFormula(COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(($I$3:$I$1485=Q14)*($A$3:$A$1485);($I$3:$I$1485=Q14)*($A$3:$A$1485)))-1)

Q14:Q18 - сектора
R14:R18 - ячейки для вывода кол-ва участков

Comment: Разместил пример в Google-таблицах, работает. Кстати, там можно не указывать последнюю строку диапазона (`$I$3:$I`)

Comment: А у меня что-то не работает....хоть убейте((

Comment: С казнью пока повременим :) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1URrgXSaTUejYCUskPxJuQvyFEMJhEoRRCCry2CvBPjw/edit#gid=0

Comment: Прямо скопировал в те же ячейки.... всё равно "-1" )))

Comment: В примере работает. Или неправильно копировали, или что-то с данными. Возможно, числовые данные сохранены на листе как текст

Comment: Заработало! А если номер участка с пометкой буквы или цифры? Можно ил заставить считаться как отдельный участок? К примеру "1058а" или "772.2"? А то сейчас именно из-за этого проблема...оказалось

Comment: См. Google-таблицу комментарий к ответу @Tunker

Comment: Всё равно считает не целыми числами... См. Google-табличку...

Answer (score 1):

E2:E3 - список секторов
в ячейку F2 введите формулу:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(($B$2:$B$8=E2)/СЧЁТЕСЛИМН($A$2:$A$8;$A$2:$A$8;$B$2:$B$8;$B$2:$B$8))
```

И растяните на весь диапазон секторов, т.е. F2:F4

Для Google Sheets

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$8=E2)/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8;$A$2:$A$8;$B$2:$B$8;$B$2:$B$8))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка
Параметр Параметр 2 в функции DIVIDE не может равняться нулю.

=SUMPRODUCT(($I$3:$I$1361=Q4)/COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$1361;$A$3:$A$1361;$I$3:$I$1361;$I$3:$I$1361))

Q4:Q8 - номера секторов
R4:R8 - ячейки для вывода кол-ва участков

Comment: Ошибка деления на ноль - в диапазоне есть пустые ячейки

Comment: Вот так вот считает по этим формулам.....

2 - 102,67 // 
3 - 85,08 // 
4 - 104,90 // 
5 - 51,50 // 
6 - 11,67

Comment: Покажите некорректный счет в Google-таблице. Формула рабочая. Корректировка для случая, когда есть пустые ячейки: `=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(($I$2:$I=Q2)/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A;$A$2:$A;$I$2:$I;$I$2:$I);)))`